# Primefaces Datatable : Filter by calendar

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, calendar, filtering

I am using PrimeFaces 5.2 . I want to filter Primefaces datatable (date column) by calendar like this:

[image]

I wrote this code but not work :

```
<p:column filterBy="#{etudiant.dateNaissance}" headerText="Naissance"
            filterMatchMode="exact">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:calendar pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect"  oncomplete="PF('etudiantTable').filter()" update="dataTable"/>
                    <p:ajax event="change" execute="@this" oncomplete="PF('etudiantTable').filter()" update="dataTable"/>   
                </p:calendar>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{etudiant.dateNaissance}" >
            <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" /> 
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
```

Any help??

Comment: I have a deja-vu...

Answer (score 3):

I found solution : add to column date filterFunction="myBean.filterByDate"

FilterByDate function :

```
public boolean filterByDate(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
    if( filter == null ) {
        return true;
    }

    if( value == null ) {
        return false;
    }

    Date dt2 = (Date) filter;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", locale);
    String date1 = sdf.format(value);
    String date2 = sdf.format(dt2);
    boolean status = date2.equals(date1);
    return status;
}
```